# How to access data from a registered SQL Server database in ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online, sql-server

Little bit of background on the problem: I have been working on a PHP application with an SQL Server backend. The application works through a web browser, but, I've recently been tasked with allowing data access through ArcGIS Server in order to be able to use Survey123 to update data in the database.

The SQL Server database has been registered with ArcGIS Server and when I go to the Site tab -> Data Stores the database name shows up in the list of data stores and has been successfully validated.

However, my question now is, how do I access the database through ArcGIS Online? More specifically, how can I connect to the database through an online map?

I've looked on Google and this site for information on this but I haven't been able to find any. Does anyone know of a good place to find information on accessing a registered database through ArcGIS Server and displaying the data in a map?

Comment: Simply; using the data store to reference data does not provide a mechanism to _access_ that data. It allows you to publish/create a service where the service will continue to reference the data from that database location (without the datastore reference the publishing process will copy data to the server and the service then uses a static copy of the data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the data from SQL DB to be viewed in an ArcGIS Online (AGOL) map you have two options:

1. Bring SQL layers into ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro and save out a map or layer package and then share it to your AGOL account then add them to a map.  Or, export out shapefiles using the software above and add those to a zip file and upload the zip directly to the AGOL map.
2. Bring the SQL layers into ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro and then publish those layers to your ArcGIS Server as a service and then add this service layer as a web layer into your AGOL map.

You cannot add SQL Server layers directly into an AGOL map without a service or export.